# Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS, Cached memory, High Load

Tags: server, ubuntu-20.04

i have a website with much traffic (many MySql selects).

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6210U CPU @ 2.50GHz (40 core(s))
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
RAM: 190 GB

As you can see on the attached image, the load seems very high.
What does Cached Memory mean ? Is it good or bad that so much memory
got cached ? If not, what can i do ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Modern operating systems do extensive use of cached memory, especially to speed up high latency operations like storage I/O. Whatever the RAM size you have, it is quite normal to have all the memory not allocated to program/kernel to be allocated for caching.

OS kernel in fact tries to foresee what data you will need from mass storage and will transfer it to RAM before you ask it, so that subsequent loads will be faster as the data is already mapped into memory.

Note that cached memory is always available for applications. In fact you can see that despite you have 1370Gb of memory allocated to cache, you also have 140Gb of available memory. This means that as soon as one of your application requires more memory, kernel will free some of the cached memory: freed memory will be the one that kernel loaded failing to foresee its need. But this is not a problem as cache loading always runs under the hood and with lower priority.

Simply put in this way: if kernel successfully preloads data that you later use, it's a improvement of overall performance; if it fails because data it's not needed, then the performance it's not affected.